# Screen readers and Access keys

Tags: html, keyboard-shortcuts, accessibility

Can HTML access keys just focus a link or a button instead of triggering the elements? Can users change existing access key value on a web page to their preferred value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `accesskey` attribute is global and can be put on any element.  However, if the element doesn't natively accept focus, then it won't do anything.  You'd have to add `tabindex='0'` to the element as well, such as

```
<span tabindex='0' accesskey='a'>foo</span>
```

Some browsers just move the focus to the element and some browsers, if the element is a "clickable" thing, such as a button or link, will activate it.  You don't have any control over that.

The user cannot change the accesskey unless you provide a UI to do so.

Accesskeys can be helpful, once they're known, but they're often not discoverable unless there's a tooltip or note on the page about them.  A tooltip will not help a keyboard-only user unless the tooltip displays when the element receives focus.  For example, on wikipedia.org, the search field has an accesskey of F but you wouldn't know it by looking at it.

Comment: I tried adding Tabindex and accesskey to a toolbar div, but it does not receive focus. Only clickable elements seem to receive focus. Any work around?

Comment: What browsers and platforms did you test with?  Which screen readers?

Comment: Tested in Google Chrome 67 on Windows. Did not use Screen Readers, just keyboard only navigation.

Comment: Your OP title says "screen readers" so I thought you were trying to get this to work with assistive technology.  Does the `tabindex='0'` work in Firefox or IE?

Comment: My Bad! That's a good catch. Nope, tabindex doesn't help in any browser.